# Cookie Overflow & Association Errors

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, chatroom

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails chatroom web application but ran into a problem while trying to update "last active" times for a user.  Each "Client" model is linked to a "LoginStatus" model through an association.  Every 5 seconds I poll the server and update the "latestNew" column for the model that is associated with the client.  However, the column 1) never updates and 2) shoots me a "Cookie Overflow" error.  Here is my code.

jquery ajax call to the "updateLoginStatus" url

```
function updateLoginStatus () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "updateLoginStatus",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            //Nothing to do on success for now
        }
    })
}
```

The controller

```
 def updateLoginStatus 
    currentUser = session[:user]
    newestTime = currentUser.login_status
    newestTime.latestTime = Time.now
    newestTime.save

    render :nothing => true
  end
```

Every time I check the console the latestNew column is still not updated.  How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the session from the user which probably contains the user-id. With this user-id you should access the User model and find this particular user. After that you are able to call login_status on the object. This is the code what you'll need to use in the controller:

```
  currentUser = User.find(session[:user])
```